# source subtag in video tag ignored by Safari

Tags: html, safari, html5-video

the following does not work with Safari 10.1

The HTML is

```
   <div class=" ">
      <video controls preload style="display: block; width: 90%;  height: auto;  margin: auto;" poster="/media/preview.png">
  <source src="media/source1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="media/source2.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="media/source3.webm" type="video/webm">
  Your browser does not support the <code>video</code> element.
</video>
```

The video won't play in Safari 10.1, in Firefox and Chrome, it does.

Moreover, in the Element information in Safari, the `source` tag seems to be not recognized. It simply doesn't appear. However, I **could** download the video (it downloaded the first mp4 version). The downloaded file **could** be opened and played by Safari.

Any help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this and this seems to work with Safari Version 10.1.1 (12603.2.4)
Please check if any class is not overriding height of player or any plugin is preventing video playback.

```html
<div class="">
  <video controls preload style="display: block; width: 90%;  height: auto;  margin: auto;">
    <source src="http://www.sample-videos.com/video/mp4/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_1mb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="http://www.sample-videos.com/video/mp4/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_1mb.mp4" type="video/mp4"> Your browser does not support the <code>video</code> element.
  </video>
</div>
```